# unity remote 5を用いたwindowsからiosへの実機検証

Tags: ios, c#, unity3d

unityを用いてwindows10でゲームの開発を始めました。
iosでの実機確認をするため手元のiphone SEにapp storeからunity rmeote 5というアプリをインストールしました。
しかしwindowsとiphoneをusbケーブルでつないで然る設定を行ってもiphone側は反応しません。

主に参考にしたサイトは[こちら](https://qiita.com/cs1000/items/e7ce11b560c1113f32f5)です。

どなたかわかる方やこうではないか、などありましたらよろしくお願いします。
一応参考のために自分が今まで行った設定などを箇条書きで記します。

- iphoneとwindows PCをusbケーブルで接続(itunesがでるので正常に接続できていると思います。)
- unity側で「Edit」「Project Settings」「Editor」を選択。
- 「Device」を選択肢の「Any iOS Device」に設定。
- Gameに切り替えて「Play」ボタンをクリック。

Comment: 1年前の記事ですが、Macのみサポートとあります。[アプリをiPhone上で Unity Remote を使って動かす](https://uni.gas.mixh.jp/unity/unity-remote.html) というか参考にされているサイトでも記述されています「※iOS端末はMacに接続しないとUnity Remoteは使用できません。」 その後機能追加されたか調べてみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一応この [マニュアル](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2018.3/Manual/UnityRemote5.html) の記述を見ると条件は満たしていそうですね。

> ノート: Unity Remoteを使用するには、開発マシンにAndroid SDKを実装する必要があります。
>
> Unity Remoteは現在Androidデバイス(WindowsやOSXとUSBで接続)とiOSデバイス(OS XやiTUnesがインストールされたWindowsとUSBで接続した iPhone、iPad、iPod touch、Apple TV) をサポートします。

参考サイトで使われているであろう2018.1版でも上記のサポートされているという記述がある
ので、Macでないと使用できないという、参考サイトの注意事項と整合性が取れないですが、
何かまだ条件があるのかも。

こんな記事もあるので、何か参考になれば。
[【Unity】Unity Remote 5 が接続されているかどうか確認する方法](http://baba-s.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/05/07/103000)

> Unity Remote 5 が接続されているかどうかは
>   　　UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected
>   このプロパティで確認できます しかし、UnityEditor 名前空間を使用する関係で、 
>   そのまま使うとアプリのビルド時にエラーが発生してしまうので、...

[【Unity】「Unity Remote 5」の使い方](https://vracademy.jp/vrunner/2017/08/unityremote/)

> 2-2. iOS (Windows)
>   1. 【Unity】iOS Build Supportをインストール
>   2. 【Unity】Edit > Project Settings > Editor > Remote：Deviceで「iPhone 〜」を選択
>   3. 【PC】iTuensをインストール (その中の Apple Mobile Device Support が必要)

そして一連のQ&Aの最後に以下が書いてあります。

> 上記を試してみても動作しない場合は、Android・iOS用でビルドを行える環境を用意しましょう。ビルドが成功していれば、Unity Remote 5 はほぼ確実に動作すると思います。